# Example of a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with derivative not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples

We know examples of a function which doesn't lie in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with derivatives in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$:
$$f_1(x) = \mathrm{arctg}(x) \notin L^2(\mathbb{R}), \qquad f_1'(x) = \frac{1}{x^2+1}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}): \qquad \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)^2\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2};$$
$$f_2(x) = \mathrm{Si}(x)\notin L^2(\mathbb{R}), \qquad f_2'(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}): \qquad \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^2\,dx = \pi;$$
$$f_3(x) = \mathrm{erf}(x)\notin L^2(\mathbb{R}), \qquad f_3'(x) = e^{-x^2}\in L^2(\mathbb{R}): \qquad \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-2x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.$$
  Are there any classical examples of such function $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ that its strong derivative $f'$ doesn't lie in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: $f(x)= \frac{\sin(e^x)}{1+x^2}$ should do it.

Comment: PhoemueX, yes, this is the kind of function I was looking for. How did you come up with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that some of $\,L^2\,$ functions are not differentiable everywhere in $\,\mathbb R$.

Second, for the more general case of weak derivatives one can easily come up with such a function.

Now, as an example let us take [$\ f(x) = \sin\left(1/x^2\right) \in L^2\left(\mathbb R\right)\,$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20sin(1%2Fx%5E2)%20from%20-infinity%20to%20infinity). 
The derivative $\,f'$ looks like  [$\ f'(x) = -2\cos\left(1/x^2\right)\big/x^3$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2fdx+(+sin(1%2fx%5e2)+)). 
Clearly [$\ f'(x)\not\in L^2\left(\mathbb R\right)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(-2+cos(1%2fx%5e2))%2fx%5e3+from+-infinity+to+infinity).