# Example of a function in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ whose second derivate is not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: operator-theory, lp-spaces, fourier-transform, laplacian

Given the fact that the Laplacian operator
\begin{align*}
        -\Delta\Psi = \mathcal{F}^{-1}(|k|^{2} \hat{\Psi}),
\end{align*}

where $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ denotes the Fourier Inverse Transform, is defined as self-adjoint in the next domain

\begin{align*} Dom(\Delta) = \{\Psi\in L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}) \:|\:
       \: |k|^{2}\hat{\Psi}(k) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})\},
\end{align*}
it is natural to ask about if there are functions in $L^{2}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ whose second derivate those not belongs to this space. Currently, this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1406874/example-of-a-function-in-l2-mathbbr-with-derivative-not-in-l2-mathbbr) covers the case for the first derivate. Next, I would provide an answer to this question and generalize the case to $L^{m}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$, where $m\geq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

By considering a not continuous function defined by intervals $[n, n+1]$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}\:\cup\:\{0\}$. We're seeking that the integral in every interval is greater than one. Thus, we propose

\begin{align*}
         \mathcal{M}(x) =
        \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
        \frac{1}{n+2}(x-n)^{n+2},& \:\:\:  x\in[n,n+1),
        \\
        0,& \:\:\: x < 0,
        \end{array}
        \right.
\end{align*}
whose second derivate is
\begin{align*}
    \mathcal{M}''(x)=
    (n+1)(x-n)^{n}
\end{align*}
for $x\in[n,n+1)$. Now, by evaluating the integral
\begin{align*}
    \int_{n}^{n+1}(n+1)^2(x-n)^{2n}dx = \dfrac{(n+1)^2}{2n+1} \geq 1\:\: \text{for}\: n\geq 1
\end{align*}
thus $\mathcal{M}''(x)$ does not belong to $L^2(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$.

Finally, these results generalizes with the following function 
\begin{align*}
    \dfrac{1}{(n+m)}(x-n)^{n+m},
\end{align*}
where $m\geq 2$ denotes the $L^m(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C})$ space to whom it doesn't belong it's $m$-derivate.